# jQueryUI - Autocomplete with json file

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an autocomplete using a json file but when I type on the input field, it shows nothing. I want to show only the data specified into "descricao", not into "codigo". Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
$('#autocompleteGrupo').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "jsonGrupo.jsp",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: request,
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: value,
                        value: item.descricao
                    };
                }));
            }
        }); 
    },  
    minLength: 2
});
});
```

my json file:

```
[{"codigo":"1","descricao":"Tecnologia da Informação"}]
```

Thanks,

Lucas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the code shown below:**

---

```
$(function() {
$('#autocompleteGrupo').autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "jsonGrupo.jsp",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: request,
        success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return(item.descricao)
            }));
        }
    }); 
   },  
   minLength: 2
  });
});
```

---

Also check that jquery ui js,css are included or not..........