# jQuery UI autoComplete with external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to write a jQuery UI autocomplete by reading an external file (i.e. data.json).  The code works fine when I try to read it from an array but if I try to read it from an external file, it doesn't work anymore!?!  Not sure why!!

Here's my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LPqBGyocpswPrEzjb1Nq?p=preview

OR

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#autocomplete1" ).autocomplete(
            {
                source:"data.json",
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#autocomplete1" ).val( ui.item.code + " - " + ui.item.label );
                    return false;
                }
            }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.code + " - " + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
                };      

        });        
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <input type="text" id="autocomplete1" size=40/>
   </body>
</html>
```

/************************************************************/

Here's the data.json file:

```
{   
    {
        "code":"YOO",
        "label":"Oshawa",
        "country":"Canada",
    },
    {
        "code":"YOW",
        "label":"Ottawa Macdonald-Cartier International",
        "city":"Ottawa",
    },
    {
        "code":"YOH",
        "label":"Oxford House",
        "city":"Oxford House",
    } 
}
```

tks

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

**[Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)**  Type: [Array](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Array) or [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String) or [Function](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function)( [Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object) request, [Function](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Function) response( [Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Object) data ) )

```
                                               Default: none; must be specified
```

> Defines the data to use, must be specified.
>   Independent of the variant you use, the label is always treated as text. If you want the label to be treated as html you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js). The demos all focus on different variations of the source option - look for one that matches your use case, and check out the code.

Multiple types supported:

- > **Array**: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
  >
  > - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
  > - An array of objects with `label` and `value` properties: `[ { label:    "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`
  >
  > The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value
  >   will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item.
  >   If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if
  >   you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the
  >   label.
- > **String**: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It
  >   can be on the same host or on a different one (*must provide
  >   JSONP*). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results,
  >   instead a query string is added with a term field, which the
  >   server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example,
  >   if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user
  >   types `foo`, a GET request would be made to
  >   `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same
  >   format as the local data described above.
- > **Function**: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
  >   Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
  >
  > - A request object, with    a single term property, which refers to the
  >     value currently in the    text input. For example, if the user enters
  >     "new yo" in a city field,    the Autocomplete term will equal "new
  >     yo".
  > - A response callback, which    expects a single argument: the data to
  >     suggest to the user. This data    should be filtered based on the
  >     provided term, and can be in any of    the formats described above
  >     for simple local data. It's important    when providing a custom
  >     source callback to handle errors during the    request. You must
  >     always call the response callback even if you    encounter an error.
  >     This ensures that the widget always has the    correct state.
  >
  > When filtering data locally, you can make use of the
  >   built-in `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex` function. It'll take a single
  >   string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result
  >   safe to pass to `new RegExp()`.

You're specifying a `string`. The key point here is:

> The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the **server-side script should use for filtering the results**. For example, if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

The string if meant to specify a `url` to hit, which returns the data in specified format.

jQueryui autocomplete doesn't directly accept a JSON, hence your code isn't working. You should specify a valid data source.

*Their plugin, their rules :)*

Related:

- [jQuery UI Autocomplete using a static json file as source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695931/jquery-ui-autocomplete-using-a-static-json-file-as-source)
- [jQuery UI autocomplete bring data from a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376312/jqueryui-autocomplete-with-json-file)
- [jQueryUI - Autocomplete with json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376312/jqueryui-autocomplete-with-json-file)